# Issues with forms

Tags: django, django-forms

What if I want to display a register and a login form on same page?

Can I do that through url.py or do I have to use multi forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super-easy-not-so-DRY-way is to just hardwrite the registration-form into the login-template file and POST the data to the registration-url. Works fine for me.